# Execution context confusion

Tags: javascript, scope

I know that JavaSript hasn't block-level scopes so why JShint throws this error:

**Variable `warning` might not have been initialized.**

```
function x(){
   if(y<allQuestions.length && document.getElementById('warning')<1) {
        var warning = document.createElement('p');
        warning.id = 'warning';
        warning.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Please check an answer!'));
        wrapper.appendChild(warning);

        setTimeout(function(){
            if (document.getElementById('warning')) {
                wrapper.removeChild(document.getElementById('warning'));
            }
        }, 2500);

    }else{
         //HERE is the problem
         warning.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Your response is still worng!'));

    }
}
```

Without the else statemenet it recognizes the variable and the code works.

Comment: Not relevant to the topic of the variable, your test to see if an element is in the DOM will work, but it's a really weird way to do things. The `getElementById()` function will return `null` when the element isn't found.

Comment: A better statement is document.getElementById('warning') != null, right?

Comment: Yes, that'd be a more typical way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case wherein JSHint is exactly right. Think about your code: where is `warning` declared and initialized?  If the code makes it to the `else` clause, how will `warning` have a value?

Move the `var` declaration and initialization out of the `if` block:

```
function x(){
    var warning = document.createElement('p');
    if (y<allQuestions.length && document.getElementById('warning')<1) {
```

Keep in mind that variable *declarations* are hoisted to the top of functions, but variable *initializations* are not.  Thus your original code was equivalent to:

```
function x(){
    var warning;
    if (y<allQuestions.length && document.getElementById('warning')<1) {
      warning = document.createElement('p');
      // ...
```

Comment: Ah.. I see! I tried to declare again a variable with the same name but JShint throws the 'duplicate declaration' error.